# Split account question

Tags: support, status-completed

I seem to have a split account. My user name has 2 addresses with 2 different profiles. User 20397 and 20270.
Can someone fix this for me please or let me know how I can fix it.

These are the two links.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/20397/jitter

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/20270/jitter

Answer (score 3):

Merged.

Your earlier account was unregistered, which means that Stack Exchange was keeping track of it by way of browser cookies which is fragile. Now that you have registered this should not happened again.

For future reference you could have flagged any one of your questions (from either account), used the "other" reason and explained there rather than opening a meta question. Not that this has done any harm, but it is a transient problem and there is no need for a public record.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I will do that if I have enough points to flag.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about [that limitation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts).